# Setting SMTP in web.config dynamically from database in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wonder if there is a way to set the SMTP credential that is usually stored in web.config using data from database.

The scenario is like this: I am sending emails using an SMTP server. The SMTP credential is as follow:

```
<smtp from="sender@domain.com">
    <network enableSsl="true" host="mail.domain.com" port="2525" userName="sender@domain.com" password="password" />
</smtp>
```

I am thinking if in the future the password changes, I will need to open the web.config and replace it manually. I think it would be better if all the variables (from, host, port, username and password) can be extracted from the database. So when I want to change anything, I will be able to change it using the web site UI. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the username password by doing something like

```
 string userName = "userName";
 string password = "password";
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
 client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
```

Just get the username and password from the database if you would like.

However I would ask why are you worried about the password changing frequently enough that this is a problem?  This is going to cause another DB hit just because there is a small chance that a sys admin will want to change a password one day, which is usually a big deal because most other apps that use the smtp server likely will have this setting in the web.config or app.config.  In my experience changes like this usually occur during a release which normally means a code deploy anyway and changing your config should be easy at this point.